# How is the RAT on the Airbus A320 family manually deployed?

Tags: airbus-a320, emergency-procedures, rat

I watched [Captain Joe's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9yz6Gd216o) on this topic but he only said in case the RAT does not deploy that you can manually deploy it from the cockpit, but unfortunately he never stated how this worked? (I'm only new to the industry and just an av geek)

Comment: Jack, welcome to Aviation.SE. I took the freedom to add a link to a video of Capt. Joe which I think is what you are referring to. If I was wrong, please revert the edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Ram Air Turbines get deployed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/how-do-ram-air-turbines-get-deployed)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe as the other question details only automatic deployment.

Comment: Thanks all for answering!

Answer (score 6):

There is a pushbutton on the overhead panel in the hydraulics section to manually deploy the RAT:

[image: A320 Hydraulics Panel]

> **5 RAT MAN ON pb**
>
> The flight crew may extend the RAT at any time by pressing the RAT MAN ON pushbutton.
>
> *Note: The RAT extends automatically if AC BUS 1 and AC BUS 2 are lost. (refer to 1.24.20).*

<sup>([A320 FCOM - Hydraulics](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Hydraulic.html) - Controls and Indicators)</sup>

There is another button on overhead panel in the EMER ELEC PWR section, which will also deploy the RAT and connect the emergency generator:

[image: A320 EMER ELEC PWR panel]

> **1 MAN ON pb (guarded)**
>
> AUTO: When the following conditions are met:
>
> - AC BUS 1 is not electrically supplied.
> - AC BUS 2 is not electrically supplied.
> - Aircraft speed is greater than 100 knots.
>
> .
>
> - The RAT extends.
> - The blue hydraulics system drives the emergency generator.
> - As soon as the emergency generator electrical parameters are within tolerance and the landing gear is retracted, the emergency generator is connected to the aircraft network.
>
> Pressed: This selects manual RAT extension. Emergency generator coupling occurs 3 seconds after the RAT supplies the emergency generator.

<sup>([A320 FCOM - Electrical](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Electrical.html) - Controls and Indicators)</sup>

Here is the full RAT deployment and emergency generator logic from the FCOM:

[image: RAT logic]

Comment: There is another switch for manual RAT deployment on the emergency power panel. The emergency power panel deploys the RAT in hydraulics back-up mode, and if the buses are not powered, it connects to the electrical bus. Deploying the RAT from the hydraulics panel only pressurizes the blue hydraulics line, it does not provide power.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks, I completely overlooked that! I added it to the answer.